# Trouble importing a sql file into mysql from command line

Tags: mysql, command-prompt, git-bash

This might be a really stupid question so apologies in advance if this upsets anyone. I'm using mysql in git bash (tried cmd as well) and can't seem to figure out how to import a sql file I exported from VS code into mysql using the command prompt.

I tried all the solutions I could find here but it keeps giving me errors like this.

```
mysql> SOURCE C:/Users/smuf2/Downloads/person.sql \g
```

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SOURCE C:/Users/s muf2/Downloads/person.sql' at line 1`

```
mysql> SOURCE C:\Users\smuf2\Downloads\person.sql \g
```

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SOURCE C:\Users\s muf2\Downloads\person.sql' at line 1`

```
mysql> winpty mysql -u root -p test < 'C:/Users/smuf2/Downloads/person.sql' \g
```

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'winpty mysql -u r oot -p test < 'C:/Users/smuf2/Downloads/person.sql'' at line 1`

```
mysql> winpty mysql -u root -p test < 'C:\Users\smuf2\Downloads\person.sql' \g
```

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'winpty mysql -u r oot -p test < 'C:\Users\smuf2\Downloads\person.sql'' at line 1`

```
mysql> winpty mysql -u root -p test < C:/Users/smuf2/Downloads/person.sql \g
```

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'winpty mysql -u r oot -p test < C:/Users/smuf2/Downloads/person.sql' at line 1`

```
mysql> winpty mysql -u root -p test < C:\Users\smuf2\Downloads\person.sql \g
```

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'winpty mysql -u r oot -p test < C:\Users\smuf2\Downloads\person.sql' at line 1`

```
mysql> mysql -u root -p test < C:/Users/smuf2/Downloads/person.sql \g
```

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u roo t -p test < C:/Users/smuf2/Downloads/person.sql' at line 1`

```
mysql> mysql -u root -p test < C:\Users\smuf2\Downloads\person.sql \g
```

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u roo t -p test < C:\Users\smuf2\Downloads\person.sql' at line 1`

I've been learning postgres and can do this easily with \i filename but can't figure out why I can't do it in mysql. I'm using mysql 8.0.26.

Comment: All the command you list after your `mysql> SOURCE C:\Users\smuf2\Downloads\person.sql \g` attempts must not be expected in the MySQL shell (`mysql>` and the error message indicates that you try to run those in the MySQL shell)

Comment: Changed the title. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can import the file without first logging to MySQL.

Just open your shell/git-bash and do:

```
mysql -u username -p password database_name < dump.sql
```

Comment: Tried it and got stdin is not a tty

Comment: Try it from your normal shell - cmd/powershell.